# How to create and customize 'NewDocSet.aspx' in SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, document-set

Is there any better way to create a new copy of the `NewDocSet.aspx` and then customize the copied file for a particular custom Document Set created?

What I urgently need to do is to add an additional custom scripts to the existing form and at the moment, I'm not sure of any other available methods to do so.